# Mysql CURDATE() not work with timestamp type

Tags: php, mysql

I've field with datatype as `timestamp` in mysql table

fetch the rows that matches the current date

`SELECT * FROM revenue WHERE date=CURDATE()`

But it returns the empty result set

Comment: timestamp contains time information but CURDATE() not. You need convert date field to just date.

Comment: But i can't convert it to date bcz app uses multiple time zones

Comment: Instead of CURDATE() use NOW().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the `date` part of timestamp as timestamp itself represents time in milliseconds, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM revenue 
WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Its worked one more question how a date between query is used for this field??

Comment: @iambatman sorry, I didn't get it. Do you want to use this field in `BETWEEN` operator?

Comment: Yes Between operator

Answer (score 0):

use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, modify it to your format requirement, with TO_CHAR specifying the format. Your query may look like this depending on the date format.

```
SELECT * 
FROM revenue 
WHERE date=TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM revenue WHERE DATE(date)=CURDATE()
```

DATE(date) should give you a date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD as well as CURDATE()